# What is the most battle tested official goto configuration for Magento1 using nginx?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, nginx, server-setup, enterprise-1.14

By doing some googling I've found [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/nginx.html) as the only documentation that seemed "official" regarding Nginx.

Is it really that the official Magento1 Nginx configuration only sits in [this quite "obscure" repository](https://gist.github.com/gwillem/cd5ae6845fa33aa0d481)? By obscure I mean, not a Magento official one.

What is the most battle-tested official goto configuration for Magento1 using Nginx?

It should:

- Support multi-websites
- Be secure
- Be in the PHP 5.X branch (the officially supported PHP version).

Answer (score 0):

you can pretty run the default nginx setup. because magento patches are more important in this case. keep good code and install magento patches.

> magento 1 official nginx config is broken. dont use it.
>
> "obscure" repository is just a bunch of useless copy-paste, not really effective, because magento patches superseded it.

but if you want to try something more complex, we use this:

Magento 1,2 nginx config:

```
https://github.com/magenx/Magento-nginx-config
```

Complete server config with some extra goodies (install and configure everything):

```
https://github.com/magenx/Magento-Automated-Server-Configuration-from-MagenX
```

p.s. php 5.x is gone by now, use php 7.0